# Russian symbols in PDF (pdfkit)

Tags: node.js, utf-8, pdfkit

Сreate a pdf file following the example https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/generate-invoices-pdfkit-node/

the problem is that characters in Russian are displayed : "Aô@Cä2CT@C¤0", but should be "Проверка". How can I set encoding to UTF-8?

```
function createInvoice(invoice, path) {
  let doc = new PDFDocument({ margin: 50 });

  generateHeader(doc);

  doc.end();
  doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));
}

function generateHeader(doc) {
  doc
    .image("logo.png", 50, 45, { width: 50 })
    .fillColor("#444444")
    .fontSize(20)
    .text("Проверка", 110, 57)
    .fontSize(10)
    .text("Проверка", 100, 65, { align: "right" })
    .text("Проверка", 100, 80, { align: "right" })
    .moveDown();
}
```

Comment: How did you create the pdf? BTW probably you should change the font: old legacy (and few) fonts in PDF use legacy encoding for compatibility reasons, all other fonts (and text) must be unicode

Comment: function createInvoice(invoice, path) {
  let doc = new PDFDocument({ margin: 50 });

  generateHeader(doc);

  doc.end();
  doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));
}

function generateHeader(doc) {
  doc
    .image("logo.png", 50, 45, { width: 50 })
    .fillColor("#444444")
    .fontSize(20)
    .text("Проверка", 110, 57)
    .fontSize(10)
    .text("Проверка", 100, 65, { align: "right" })
    .text("Проверка", 100, 80, { align: "right" })
    .moveDown();
}

Comment: Note: you should edit your question, adding such details.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the font file and include it:

```
.font(`${__dirname}/arial.ttf`)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to use a font which support russian characters

Look this thread
https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/issues/262